# Unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: asp.net

Getting this exception. On debugging the current instance im  visual studio  getting the error at

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path))) {
                w.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                string err = "@ Page: " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() +
                              ". Message:" + errorMessage;
                w.WriteLine(err);
                w.Flush();
                w.Close();
 }
```

On commenting this block everything is working properly. Please help to resolve the error in this code

Comment: In which line you getting the error?

Comment: @user2859092 so where are you calling this from?

Comment: And not that it matters, but instead of `w.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` you can just do `w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString*CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` Also, the `Close()` is unnecessary since the streamwriter will be closed when it's disposed by the `using`

Comment: Does your code work if you assign "test" to err (instead of current code)?